# How to run a query with group by over a 'select_related' field in django ORM

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I'm developing a reservations system and on my database I have Products, different Items of the products and orders related to specific items. The intention is to get the list of available items of an specific product that are not already reserved between two dates.

These are my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product.name} - {self.name}"


class Order(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    assigned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item.name} - {self.start_date} - {self.end_date}"
```

After some tests in SQL in the database, I've reached the following query that gives me the expected result:

```
SELECT calendarapp_item.id, calendarapp_item.product_id as product, count(orders.id) AS active_orders
FROM calendarapp_item
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM calendarapp_order WHERE start_date<='{}' AND end_date>='{}' AND status='completed')  AS orders
ON orders.item_id=calendarapp_item.id
GROUP BY calendarapp_item.id
HAVING active_orders=0 and product={}
```

I would like to translate this query to Django ORM in order to avoid conflicts when switching between backends databases. I would like to know if this is possible. I would also accept recommendations on improving the query if possible.

I've managed to get the list of orders that I should take into account.

```
ongoing_orders = Order.objects.filter(start_date__lte=end_dt, end_date__gte=init_dt, status='completed', item__product__id = product_id)
```

But right now I would like to count the orders grouping them by the related item and filter the items where the count is 0.